# Deploy WCF service on IIS that's visible from public IP

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis

I've managed to get my WCF service working on IIS express and IIS locally via localhost.  I was wondering how I can deploy the service so that it can be accessed outside my network i.e http: // public ip.   I've done a lot of digging around and can't seem to find the right answer.

I've tried setting the IP bindings on IIS to my public IP but I get 'Bad request - invalid hostname'.

I have opened all necessary ports and host my own apache server which is accessible outside my network, so I know that the ports side of things is fine.  I'm just having issues with the server hosting (IIS).

Any ideas how this can be achieved?

Comment: Suggestion - setup IIS just so you can get to a simple HTML page, then an ASP.Net page. If you get past this point you've checked off things like network access, IP addressing, routing, etc., DNS, and IIS setup (deal with WCF and such after). At this stage, it's too broad...hth..

Comment: Is this on a home network?

Comment: Yes this is on a home network.

Comment: So am I supposed to be pointing all my IP address settings in IIS at the localhost/computers internal IP rather than the public IP?